# FFmpeg Node.js live web streaming

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, hapi.js

I'm trying to create some kind of proxy server to get IP cameras feeds and stream it over http using FFmpeg and hapi.js
The main thing is that must exist outside http-server routes regardless of being watched. So I create feed like that

```
let ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')

let ffproc = ffmpeg()
    .input('some_link')
    .format('flv')
    .videoCodec('copy')
    .noAudio()


  let feed = ffproc.pipe({end: true})
```

and http-server

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')

const server = new Hapi.Server({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000
})

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/live',
  handler: function (request, h) {
      return feed
  }
})

server.start((err) => {   
  console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`)
})
```

I've got my feed using vlc or ffplay but after I disconnect `ffproc` ends as well so I cannot reconnect later.
I've tryed to **clone** or **pipe** stream but it doesn't help, process still exists but ffplay shows error 'Invalid data found when processing input' instead of feed. `koa` server shows same behaviour, `express` and `fastify` I did not managed to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: Your issue is that after you disconnect from checking your feed via vlc or ffplay, you can't reconnect afterwards?

If you need the stream to operate continuously outside of the server routes then you should move feed creation to an entirely separate process and tie your server into that process output as needed. What is likely happening is that when you disconnect the scope of the feed variable is changing and it's no longer globally accessible where it once was, so the server can't recall it when you try to reconnect.